# set a div's min height depending on a height of another div

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```

.given the example above, how do I set the height of div2 as the minimum height of div1? also vice versa by using only css. TIA!

Comment: I don't see an example. Please refine your question.

Comment: the size of either one of them will affect the size of the container, so you shouldnt have any problem. do you have a specific example? like are you floating the inside divs?

Comment: .both div1 and div2 are floated inside container div. actually, i'm not having any problems with the height of the container div. only with div1 and div2. because I want the size of those two to be always equal regardless on which one is containing more texts inside.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that using css... not dynamically.

`#div1 + #div2 {}` will let you target div2 occuring only after div1 but you cant make the height relate to the previous element, you just have to hard code it.

```
#div1 {min-height: 100px;}
#div1 + #div2 { height: 100px;}
```

Comment: .then, what's the other way around this?

Comment: you could use javascript... it would be better if you tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish as opposed o just asking how to relate the height of two elements.

Comment: .I want both divs' height to be set as auto because the content of each divs are changing every now and then.

Comment: .because that is the solution that I have come up with. if both divs' min-height will be based on the height of each other then they will always be equal.

Comment: they wouldnt always be equal, one could be larger than the min-height.

Answer (score 0):

.I figure out another way around it, but not actually by inheriting the size of each other. I decided to create a background image matching the background colors of both divs and then applying it to the container div.

Comment: that's known as the ["faux columns"](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) technique, and it is usually the easiest way to do this ;)

Answer (score 0):

add the same class on both div1 and div2 then set the min height of the class added

```
<style>
        .SomeClass{
          height:500px;
          min-height: 300px}
   </style>

 <div id="container">
     <div id="div1" class="SomeClass">
  </div>
  <div id="div2"  class="SomeClass">
  </div>
</div>
```